# How link a FastAPI Model to a mongoDB collection?

Tags: mongodb, fastapi, pydantic

I have a mongo db collection with 968 documents. I want to my API get one of this documments when i call a get request. How I can link a pydantic model with this collection that already existis?
Model:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Stock(BaseModel):
    cotacao: int
    pl: int
    pvp: int
    psr: int
    dy: int
```

route:

```
from fastapi import APIRouter
from config.db import connection
from models.stock import Stock
from schemas.stock import stock_entity

stock_router = APIRouter(
    tags=['stock'],
    prefix='/stock'
)

@stock_router.get('/')
async def get_stocks():
    return connection.local.stock.find()
```

schema:

```
def stock_entity(db_item) -> dict:
    return {
        "id" : str(db_item['_id'].values()),
        "cotacao": db_item['cotacao'],
        "pl": db_item['pl'],
        "pvp": db_item['pvp'],
        "psr": db_item['psr'],
        "dy": db_item['dy'],
       
    }

def stock_list_entity(db_item) -> list:
    stock_list = []
    for item in db_item:
        stock_list.append(stock_entity(item))
    return stock_list
```

The colection:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, its realy simple:

config.db

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from pathlib import os

load_dotenv()
connection = MongoClient(str(os.getenv('DATABASE_CONNECTION_STRING')))
db = connection.eazy_indicator
ibov_collection = connection.eazy_indicator.ibov
```

route:

```
from config.db import connection, db, ibov_collection
from models.stock import Stock
from schemas.stock import stock_entity, stock_list_entity

stock_router = APIRouter(
    tags=['stock'],
    prefix='/stock'
)

@stock_router.get('/')
async def get_all_stocks() -> list:
    return stock_list_entity(ibov_collection.find())
```